# Komodo Edit - How to modify the default "Find all functions" regex

Tags: komodo, findall, activestate, komodoedit

In Komodo Edit 6.1 , there is a nice feature to find and highlight all the functions (navigation->Find all functions ctrl+F8). It searches based on a Regex to find all the functions, which is this :

```
^[  ]*?(def\s+[^\(]+\([^\)]*?\):|class\s+[^:]*?:)
```

But there is a minor problem with it, if there are some blank spaces between the ")" and ":" , which technically  is correct but this Regex won't match. 
I want to modify it to :

```
^[  ]*?(def\s+[^\(]+\([^\)]*?\) *:|class\s+[^:]*?:)
```

There is only one additional "{space}*" before first ":"

But I don't know where to find the default value for this configuration. 
I even tried about:config but it wasn't there too.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> immediately after <kbd>Ctrl+F8</kbd> to view and modify the regex. Save it as a [macro](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/macros.html) and bind the macro to a keyboard shortcut:

```
 komodo.assertMacroVersion(2);
 if (komodo.view && komodo.view.scintilla) { komodo.view.scintilla.focus(); } // bug 67103

 Find_ReplaceAllInMacro(window, 2, '(^[ |\t]*?(?:([\w|\.|_]*?)\s*=\s*function|function\s*([\w|\_]*?)|([\w|\_]*?)\s*:\s*function).*?$)', '\\1', true, 2, 0, false, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would really do the job. 
Although I have switched to SublimeText2 and not using Komodo anymore.